# Windows 8 error browsing network drive

Tags: inno-setup

When I try to expand a network drive from the 'Browse' button on the
'Select Destination Location' setup page I get a 'refers to a location 
that is not available' error (see first screenshot), the network drive
icons don't display either.

The network drive permissions allow all users read/write drive access
and other apps do not have the same problem (the dialog in the second
screenshot was generated by a 32-bit app calling the SHBrowseForFolder
API).

The environment is Windows 8 (64-bit) with all updates as of
16-Jul-2013 running as a VirtualBox 4.2.16 client. The setup has been
compiled with the latest version of Inno Setup (5.5.3 (a)).

The problem is exhibited by both Samba and Windows shares.
Windows 7 and XP do not have the same problem.  I haven't tested it on
a dedicated (non VirtualBox) Win8 PC.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, ANSI version of InnoSetup is being compiled with Delphi 2.01, which was released in 1997 (16 years ago). As first I would suggest at least *upgrade* to Unicode version of InnoSetup (even if that probably won't resolve this problem).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I recompiled with the Unicode version (5.5.3 (u)) but still get the same error.

Comment: By default Windows does not cache login credentials between elevated and non-elevated processes.  You logged into the server and mapped the drive letter as a non-elevated user; this is not available to an elevated process such as an installer.

Comment: That's the answer, many thanks! Setting [Setup] PrivilegesRequired=lowest fixed it. Interesting that it only happens on Win8.

Comment: @Miral Stuart said that your suggestion solved his problem, so would you please post it as a formal answer to the question? If Miral doesn't respond in a few days, you could do this yourself, Stuart (answering one's own question is encouraged here) so that you would be able to accept an answer and mark this question resolved.

Answer (score 2):

By default Windows does not cache login credentials between elevated and non-elevated processes. You logged into the server and mapped the drive letter as a non-elevated user; this is not available to an elevated process such as an installer.

You can set `PrivilegesRequired=lowest` in the `[Setup]` section to prevent elevation and keep network drives available; however bear in mind that doing this will also prevent access to any admin-required locations or functionality on the local machine.

If you are creating a "pure" network installer (that does not install any local files), you may also wish to use settings like `Uninstallable=no`.  Alternatively, you could redesign your installer to run locally on the server machine instead.

Answer (score 1):

This problem annoyed me to for quite a while as well, until I found an easy solution:

In the registry just set [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System] "EnableLinkedConnections"=dword:00000001

reboot, and be done with it.

Over the background and possible drawbacks read [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94528/does-enabling-enablelinkedconnections-pose-a-security-risk) and [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ee844140(v=ws.10).aspx)

When it comes to Inno Setup, one can also follow this approach:
[Make Inno Setup installer request privileges elevation only when needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556853/make-inno-setup-installer-request-privileges-elevation-only-when-needed). Esp. when one does not want to ask customers to change this registry key. I am doing it like that and it works quite fine.