# Run setup as admin based on a runtime condition

Tags: inno-setup, uac, shellexecute, runas

I have an InnoSetup installer that can usually run as non-admin, but in some cases it needs to run with elevated privileges if a condition is met. So I set `PrivilegesRequired` to `lowest` to ensure it doesn't show the UAC prompt when not required, and if the condition is met, I try to restart it as admin like this:

```
if not ShellExec('runas', ExpandConstant('{srcexe}'), GetCmdTail(), '', SW_HIDE, ewNoWait, errorCode) then begin
  MsgBox(SysErrorMessage(errorCode), mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

But it always fail with error 5 : access denied.

Apparently it's not because I can't use the `runas` verb: running another executable with that verb works fine, and shows the UAC prompt. I also tried copying setup.exe to the temp directory and running it from there, but the copy fails.

How can I restart my setup as admin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make InnoSetup installer request privileges elevation only when needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556853/make-innosetup-installer-request-privileges-elevation-only-when-needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the limitation of the `ShellExec` function. It [`explicitly compares`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_4/Projects/ScriptFunc_R.pas#L836) if the file that you're going to execute is not the installer itself and if so, [`it fails`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_4/Projects/ScriptFunc_R.pas#L851) with [`ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED). So, you just can't run the installer with the `ShellExec` function.

In [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21565479/960757) I've had to use [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Windows API function to workaround this limit, and you can do the same.

Comment: It worked, thanks! However my question is clearly a duplicate, I should probably close it...

Comment: It wouldn't be duplicate if you would ask why does `ShellExec` fail to run `{srcexe}` which is already part of your question and what I actually answered :-)