# Inno Setup return only user specified command line switches

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

The support function `GetCmdTail` returns all command line parameters passed to Setup or Uninstall as a single string. This produces:

> /SL5="$A808E8,550741730,269824,D:\Setup.exe" /DEBUGWND=$6A0ACA /verysilent /suppressmsgboxes /closeapplications /restartapplications /norestart

Is there another function or simple way of just returning the user specified command line switches:

> /verysilent /suppressmsgboxes /closeapplications /restartapplications
>   /norestart

in this particular case, whilst excluding the `/DEBUGWND` entry and/or any other parameters that have not been user specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Inno Setup 6.2, [`ParamCount` and `ParamStr` exclude some of these internal parameters](https://groups.google.com/g/innosetup/c/pDSbgD8nbxI), so the `if` condition in the below code is not needed.*

---

Based on a similar code I use to [run an elevated installer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21556853/850848#35435534):

```pascal
function GetUserCmdTail: string;
var
  I: Integer;
  S: string;
begin
  for I := 1 to ParamCount do
  begin
    S := ParamStr(I);
    { Filter all internal Inno Setup switches }
    if (CompareText(Copy(S, 1, 5), '/SL5=') <> 0) and
       (CompareText(Copy(S, 1, 10), '/DEBUGWND=') <> 0) and
       (CompareText(Copy(S, 1, 10), '/SPAWNWND=') <> 0) and
       (CompareText(Copy(S, 1, 11), '/NOTIFYWND=') <> 0) and
       (CompareText(S, '/DETACHEDMSG') <> 0) and
       (CompareText(S, '/DebugSpawnServer') <> 0) then
    begin
      Result := Result + AddQuotes(S) + ' ';
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. Works perfectly.