# How to create registry key in HKLM using Inno Setup without requiring Administrator permissions

Tags: windows, registry, inno-setup, elevated-privileges

I am developing desktop application using C# and creating setup using Inno setup compiler.

Let me explain application functionality,

1. I have created application Setup using Inno Setup all user (i.e. application can install in admin/non admin PC).

   ```
   //all user
   PrivilegesRequired=lowest
   ```
2. While installing application, I want to create registry key in `HKLM`. For this I have added registry key in Inno Setup script as below

   ```
   [Registry]
   Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TestKey"; Permissions: users-modify; \
       Flags: uninsdeletekey createvalueifdoesntexist; ValueType: string; \
       ValueName: "SOAPAddress"; ValueData: "ABC"
   ```
3. While installing application registry key not created its throws below exception

   ```
   ---------------------------
   Error
   ---------------------------
   Error creating registry key:

   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\TestKey

   RegCreateKeyEx failed; code 5.

   Access is denied.

   Click Retry to try again, Ignore to proceed anyway, or Abort to cancel installation.
   ```

Please help me, How can I create  registry key in `HKLM` using Inno Setup compiler.

I had checked in VS2010 its create registry key but setup can't run non-admin PC.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

You need Administrator privileges to write to `HKLM`. So you cannot use the `PrivilegesRequired=lowest`.

And creating an user-writable key in `HKLM` is a bad practice.

You cannot have an installer that can be run by a non-admin user, yet be able to write to `HKLM`. That's a basic principle of Windows security.

---

It's not really clear what you mean by *"application can install in Admin/non admin PC"*, but maybe you are actually looking for this:
[Make Inno Setup installer request privileges elevation only when needed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21556853/850848).