# Install files in different folder if the privileges is not administrator in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, privileges

I want to use script like below

```pascal
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := not IsAdminLoggedOn;
  if Result then
  begin
```

to check if the user is administrator or not.

But how can I do if user is administrator, then install `A.txt` in `C:\program files\ABC`, otherwise in `D:\TEST`?

Can I write something to connect to `[Files]`?

Because I also want to use check path when installing files, if I can combine `[Code]` and `[Files]` it might be easier for me.

Excuse for my lack of knowledge, and thanks in advance.

I've tried to use this,

```
[Files]
Source: "..\ABC\CDE.txt"; DestDir: "{code:GetDirName}\IJK"; \
    Check: DirExists(ExpandConstant('C:\Program Files\FGH'))
```

But I don't know how to write the code, if I want to install more files in more path.

This one doesn't work:

```pascal
function GetDirName(Param: string): string;
begin
  if IsAdminLoggedOn And DirExists(ExpandConstant('C:\ABC')) then
  begin
    Result := ExpandConstant('C:\ABC\My Program')
  end
    else
  begin
    if DirExists(ExpandConstant('C:\DEF')) then
    begin
      Result := ExpandConstant('C:\DEF\My Other Program');
    end
      else
    begin
      MsgBox('No destination found, aborting installation', mbError, MB_OK);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just implement the [`GetDirName` scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) to return a different path for privileged and un-privileged installation.

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "..\ABC\CDE.txt"; DestDir: "{code:GetDirName}"

[Code]

function GetDirName(Param: string): string;
begin
  if IsAdminLoggedOn then
    Result := ExpandConstant('{pf}\My Program')
  else
    Result := ExpandConstant('{localappdata}\My Program');
end;
```

---

If you want to use different folders for different files, just implement more functions like `GetDirName`. Though if the difference is only about subfolders, you can of course use one scripted constant function to resolve the common root folder and append the subfolder in the `DestDir` parameter.

---

If you want to change an overall installation target, use the `GetDirName` scripted constant in the [`DefaultDirName` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_defaultdirname):

```
[Setup]
DefaultDirName={code:GetDirName}

[Files]
Source: "..\ABC\CDE.txt"; DestDir: "{app}"

[Code]
{ The same as above }
```

---

For a more complex example, see [Make Inno Setup installer request privileges elevation only when needed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21556853/850848).