# New lines in SelectDirBrowseLabel get cut by directory edit box

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I have the following lines in my installer setup

```pascal
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if IsAdmin then
    WizardForm.SelectDirBrowseLabel.Caption := 'Installation directory:'
  else
    WizardForm.SelectDirBrowseLabel.Caption := 'Restart installer as Administrator to install {#AppName} system wide.' #13#10 + #13#10 + 'Installation directory:';
end;
```

The problem is that the text on the new lines gets cut by the directory entry box so they are not visible.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add the info label below the edit box instead:

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  InfoLabel: TNewStaticText;
begin
  InfoLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  InfoLabel.Parent := WizardForm.SelectDirPage;
  InfoLabel.Left := WizardForm.SelectDirLabel.Left;
  InfoLabel.Top := WizardForm.DirEdit.Top + WizardForm.DirEdit.Height + ScaleY(16);
  InfoLabel.Caption :=
    'Restart installer as Administrator to install {#AppName} system wide'
end;
```

[image]

---

Though would this be a better solution?
[Make Inno Setup installer request privileges elevation only when needed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21556853/850848)